# running a command stored in a bash variable

Tags: bash, macos

So I'm trying to capture the IP address of a Parallels VM guest (Win8) from the host (OS X).  I thought a bash script would be good for this.  The ultimate goal is to have a single command that will fetch the IP address and then initiate an ssh port redirect.

I am aware of the `prlctl enter` command, and I do not believe it supports port redirection.

My script thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash

VM="Win8 Dev"
CMD="prlctl exec \"$VM\" ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | grep -m1 -o '\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}'"
echo $CMD
IP=$($CMD)
echo $IP
```

output:

```
prlctl exec "Win8 Dev" ipconfig | grep IPv4 | grep -m1 -o
'\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}' Failed to get VM config:
The virtual machine could not be found. The virtual machine is not
registered in the virtual machine directory on your Mac. Contact the
Parallels support team for assistance.
```

So it appears that the CMD variable is being populated correctly, but something is getting lost when trying to assign the output of the command to the IP variable.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you run `prlctl exec "Win8 Dev" ipconfig` directly in the shell, does it work correctly? Same for the whole content of $CMD.

Comment: i think it would work if you use eval or just the command as is instead of echo in your last line. cause echo simply prints what is in the Variable and does not interpret it.

Comment: @konqui: the second to last line should interpret the $CMD variable.  `IP=$($CMD)`

Comment: sorry my fault some how have overseen this line.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs to do this, here is the solution I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

VM="name of my VM"
CMD="prlctl exec \"$VM\" ipconfig | grep "IPv4" | grep -m1 -o '\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}\.\d\{1,3\}'"
IP=$(eval $CMD)

#once you have the correct data in the $IP variable you can do something with it.. I initiate an ssh session, but you can do whatever you like.
```

I have no idea why eval is needed here.  Someone more familiar with bash will be needed to answer that mystery.